# Can't display "flavors" interface in OpenStack Horizon Dashboard

Tags: django, openstack, openstack-horizon

After installing in a Ubuntu Server 13 Machine Several Openstack modules (Keystone, Glance, Nova, Neutron) I've installed Horizon.

I can log with no problem as an admin, display every menu but not the vm flavors menu.

After enabling Debugging in the django config I get this error :

```
TypeError at /admin/flavors/

list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_public'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.211.14/horizon/admin/flavors/
Django Version:     1.5.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_public'

Exception Location:     /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/api/nova.py in flavor_list, line 406
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.5
Python Path:    

['/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../..',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/',
 '/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard']
```

After tracing the error I've found that method `list()` in `class FlavorManager` has no argument `is_public`.

**Is this to be considered as a Bug or is there some misconfiguration?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked around the office and got the following reply:

Possibly they have no publicly marked flavors. In Glance when you do image-create you indicate whether others can see the image. They can update with:

glance image-update --is-public=True *uuid*

Also see if this is a Dashboard-only problem by doing:

glance image-list

and see what properties you have on the images you expect to see.

Also, if this is a flavors-only problem, use nova flavor-list to see the flavors that you'd expect to see in the Dashboard. http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-ops/content/flavors.html

Also, you can ask OpenStack questions at http://ask.openstack.org.